# How to set date of twitter bootstrap datetimepicker to a date from database without being overridden by the maxDate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a twitter bootstrap datetimepicker whose value is set from the db in a  update form. But I want to disable the dates after today in case the date is being updated, but the max date value overrides the value from the db in the input.

I want to show the date from the db in the input and simultaneously disable the dates after today. How is it done?

Here is my code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control required tobecleared service_procedure_date1"  name="uploadvm.serviceprocedurebo.Date" data-val-message="Please enter date"
    placeholder="Document Date*" value="@Model.ServiceProcedurebo.Date.ToLongDateString()" />
```

jQuery

```
$(".service_procedure_date1").datetimepicker({ format: 'DD MMMM YYYY', maxDate: new Date()});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input value should have the same format as the picker:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control required tobecleared service_procedure_date1" name="uploadvm.serviceprocedurebo.Date" data-val-message="Please enter date"
                                       placeholder="Document Date*" value="@Model.ServiceProcedurebo.Date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")" />
```

and initial value will be there until the picker is touch:

```
        $(".service_procedure_date1").datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD MMMM YYYY'
        }).on('dp.show', function (e) {
            $(this).data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(new Date());
        });
```